# how i can set group processor for multi task

Tags: c++, multitasking

i have a server with 4 core and each core has 20 processor.
totally i have 80 processor and window set them 2 processor group each group has 40 processor .
i have a process which i want use all 80 processor. so i try use "Concurenssy::task_Group" and i made 80 task. but when i run my process , my software only run in one processor group , and only 40 processor get busy by software. even in window task manager at set affinity i can select one of two processor group.

Is there any one can tell me how i can use all processor by task_Group ?

Comment: You'll have to partition these threads across groups yourself, call SetThreadGroupAffinity().  Do **not** skip perf testing, make sure you can control the number of threads with a config setting.  The processor interconnect on a machine like this can produce very disappointing outcomes.

Comment: Hi Hans. thank for your comment . but SetThreadGroupAffinity() is for threads not for Concurenssy::task_Group . can you tell me how to set affinity for task_Group ?